# Does f(n) = o((f(n))^2)?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I have a little question about the little o notation...according to the formal definition of little o, "f(n) = o(g(n)) means for all c > 0 there exists some k > 0 such that 0 ≤ f(n) < cg(n) for all n ≥ k. The value of k must not depend on n, but may depend on c."

Does f(n) = o((f(n))^2) ?

Why or why not??

Comment: If $x > 1$, then $x^2 > x$. That should be enough.

Comment: But for example, it's false if $f(n) = \frac1n$ for example.

Comment: Right. You also need: If $0 \leq x < 1$, then $x^2 < x$.

Comment: So f(n) does not equal to o((f(n))^2) because of counter example (i.e. when f(n) = 1/n)?

Comment: It is only true if $\frac1{f(n)}\to 0.$